# VB.NET Linq Enumerable (diferencias entre query Linq y métodos de extensión)

Tags: .net, linq

¿A la hora operar con Enumerables que técnica es mejor? 
¿Existen diferencias de rendimiento entre la sintaxis de query de Linq y los métodos de extensión?

Por ejemplo:

```
Lista.OrderBy(Function(n) n.apellidos).ToList()

(From n In Lista Order By n.apellidos).ToList()
```

Comment: Hola Joseba. A que te refieres con mejor?  En cuanto a tiempo de ejecución, uso de memoria , cuál es más bonita, ..

Comment: Pues todo eso, mejor performance, etc.

Comment: Para performance seguro que ya existen y si no , puedes hacer benchmarks para probar cual es más rapido... no entiendo que quieres sacar con la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Cuando hay 2 maneras de hacer lo mismo alguna diferencia habrá. ¿o no?

Comment: Pero no preguntas cuales son las diferencias, si no *cual es mejor*

Comment: ... Vale lo dejamos como pregunta mal formulada y no extrapolable para una respuesta. Me quedo con la de @Pikoh. Un saludo.

Comment: Yo reformularía la pregunta a "Existen diferencias de rendimiento entre la sintaxis de query de Linq y los métodos de extensión?" o algo asi, de esa manera encajaría mejor en el sitio yo creo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ninguna en cuanto a rendimiento, son exactamente iguales. Esto podemos comprobarlo haciendo un simple programa y comprobando la salida en IL<sup>*</sup> que produce.

Primero, usando los métodos de extensión:

```
Dim a = Lista.OrderBy(Function(n) n).ToList()
```

Esto, tras ser compilado, nos da este IL<sup>*</sup>:

```
IL_0003:  ldftn       UserQuery._Lambda$__1
IL_0009:  newobj      System.Func<System.String,System.String>..ctor
IL_000E:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy
IL_0013:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList
IL_0018:  stloc.0     // a
```

Ahora, usando LINQ:

```
Dim b = (From n In Lista Order By n).ToList()
```

Que nos da tras ser compilado:

```
IL_001B:  ldftn       UserQuery._Lambda$__2
IL_0021:  newobj      System.Func<System.String,System.String>..ctor
IL_0026:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy
IL_002B:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList
IL_0030:  stloc.1     // b
```

Como puedes ver, es exactamente el mismo. .Net proporciona ambas formas de hacer la consulta, pero en cuanto a rendimiento es lo mismo.

Hay ciertas diferencias en cuanto a usar una u otra sintaxis, pero se basan mas en la legibilidad y dependiendo del caso, a veces es mejor una u otra. Pero el rendimiento es exactamente igual.

<sub>*IL se refiere al [Common Intermediate Language](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)</sub>

<sub>Aunque el tema de las ventajas/inconvenientes es tirando a subjetivo (yo por ejemplo el 99% de las veces uso los métodos de extensión), pongo aqui dos preguntas de [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) en las que se discute el tema: [LINQ - Fluent and Query Expression - Is there any benefit(s) of one over other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/214500) y [Extension methods syntax vs query syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279701)</sub>

Comment: Muy interesante. Para los que no estamos tanto con .Net (menos aún LINQ), ¿Conocés algún recurso bueno que explique esas "*ciertas diferencias*" (excluyendo motivos obvios de legibilidad)?

Comment: @Mariano he editado la pregunta añadiendo un par de enlaces a preguntas de [so] donde se discute el tema, aunque al ser en mi opinión un poco subjetivo no se si tiene cabida en el sitio

Comment: @Mariano un tema maravilloso te lo aseguro. Si te surgen dudas, sabes donde encontrarnos  ;)

Comment: Segun el señor skeet y su librito, en la primera pasada el compilar traduce el Linq a metodos de extension (y explica como se puede probar eso) y despues el compilador compila. Por lo cual, no habria ninguna diferencia, a excepcion de como se ve en el codigo. Asi que ya depende de como se ponga de acuerdo el equipo al escribir el codigo. @Mariano